# Upgrade from win 7 to win 8

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, windows

I currently have windows 7 and latest ubuntu installed on the system.

I installed ubuntu using the wubi.exe which made it easy for me to install ubuntu from an existing windows installation.

Now if i upgrade from windows 7 to windows 8 will the current ubuntu installation get deleted ? will it be affected in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand WUBI correctly, the installation itself will not be affected as long as you do not reformat the hard disk during installation.

However, most likely you will no longer be able to boot into Ubuntu. The Windows 7 bootloader will be replaced by the new Windows 8 bootloader (without the option to boot into Ubuntu). In theory, when you run the wubi installer again, it should recognize that you have already installed ubuntu and give you the opportunity to update the Windows bootloader, **but**, and this is a large "but", I'm not sure whether Wubi can handle the new Windows 8 bootloader.

You can try it out, though; however, backup everything of value you have on the Ubuntu installation first.

Alternatively, move Ubuntu out of the Windows -- [migrate it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) to a separate partition.

Comment: if i migrate it to a separate partition... and then upgrade.. will ubuntu be available or would the bootmanager crash it?

Comment: The Windows bootmanager will not detect Ubuntu and you will have to install grub; detailed instructions are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: so if I do it this way no data is lost? I know nothing is sure but if I follow all the things I will have both win8 and ubuntu without data loss right? :)

Comment: Yes, but be careful.